# Variable not adding 1 to itself inside if statement

Tags: java

I have this method.

```
 int m = 0;
 int a = 0;
  @Override
  public void animate(long deltaMs){
   ...
        a++;
        double valor = destValue * 100f;

        if(a%17==0 && valor > 1) {
                MySQLAccess sql = new MySQLAccess();
                int p = 0;
                try {
                     p = sql.getRandom();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                m++;
                if(m == p+1) {
                MainFrame mf = new MainFrame();    
                RandomProvider randomp = new RandomProvider();
                QueryPanel qp = new QueryPanel(randomp);
                  try {
                      sql.insertScore(valor,sql.getUsuarios(qp.getUsuario()), 
                      sql.getRandom());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
          }
        repaint();
        }        
      }
```

This method executes itself multiple times on runtime, and I wanted to keep track of how many times it did, the variable "a" does get added correctly but "m" that is inside the if statement doesn't and I don't know why, I need to know how many times that if statement runs.

Comment: One word answer: **Debugger**.

Comment: fix your indentation

Comment: @leonardkraemer fixed

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I have debugged, the value of "m" is always 1, that's what I don't understand

Comment: If you are walking this method with a debugger then it should be apparent whether your `if` body is being entered or not. You assert that `m` is a constant `1`, how have you determined that?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Ok what I found out now is that there's something about animations that I don't understand sadly, the "a" variable is also "1" the first 10 times I run it or so, after that it changes to 2, It has something to do with the way animations work I guess, I'm truly lost here.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to know how many times the if statement run (and you don’t use debugger), store those times in a variable.

```
//...
int timesRun = 0;
while( ){
   if( ){
    timesRun++;
   }
}
System.out.println(“Debug: I’d statement run”+timesRun+” times”);
```

Answer (score -1):

if `MySQLAccess sql = new MySQLAccess()` throws, `m++` will not be reached.

Comment: The exception is caught, so the code after the catch will be reached!

Comment: What I don''t understand is why it's not reaching the code

Comment: `MySQLAccess sql = new MySQLAccess()` is before the `try` statement.